# PHP build an array using a dynamic variable

Tags: php

I'm attempting to build an array that uses a dynamic variable. However I keep getting the following errors:

**PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'default' in** and **PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in**

An example of what I'm doing is below; `$sectors` is a data array from a CMS and `$sectorsName` will be dynamic but left it in as a set string for the example.

```
$sectorsName = "clientsSectors";
${$sectorsName} = array();

foreach ($sectors as $sector) {
    ${$sectorsName}["default"] = array(
        "image" => "",
        "text" => "{$clients->global_textarea}"
    );
    ${$sectorsName}[$sanitizer->pageName($sector->global_text)] = array(
        "image" => "{$sector->global_image->url}",
        "text" => "{$sector->global_textarea}"
    );
    ${$sectorsName} = json_encode(${$sectorsName}, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your main `foreach` loop, this line:

```
${$sectorsName} = json_encode(${$sectorsName}, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

... is re-declaring `${$sectorsName}`.  When it goes through the loop the second time, the `["default"]` subkey is no longer there.